# Is there a system to the numbered categories

Tags: category-theory

$\mathbf{0}$ is the empty category, $\mathbf{1}$ is the category with one object, $*$, and one morphism, $1_*$, $\mathbf{2}$ is the category with two objects, etc. ...

Is there some system to these numbered categories? Could I come up with, say, category $\mathbf{15}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually two different systems of "numbered" categories I know of.  In one of them, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathbf{n}$ denotes a category with $n$ objects and no morphisms except the identity morphisms.

In the other, $\mathbf{n}$ denotes the poset $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ with its usual order.  That is, there are $n$ objects, one for each natural number $i<n$.  For $i,j<n$, there is exactly one morphism $i\to j$ if $i\leq j$, and otherwise there are no morphisms $i\to j$.

For $n=0,1$ these definitions agree but for $n\geq 2$ they are different.  In practice there is usually little risk of confusion, though, as it is easy to mention briefly what you mean and in any case it is usually easy to tell from context.

Comment: There is also another relatively common way to make the natural numbers from category theory: it is a category with one object $x$ with a non-identity morphism $g:x\to x$, such that each morphism $x\to x$ is either the identity, or the result of composing $g$ with itself some unique number of times. More rigorously, it is the coequalizer in the category of categories of the two morphisms from $\mathbf 1$ to $\mathbf 2$, as defined in this answer (the interpretation with posets).

Comment: @Arthur That turns the set of natural numbers into a category, not each natural number into its own category.

Comment: I would note that in the first case $\mathbf{n}\cong\coprod_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}$. In the second case, $\mathbf{n}$ can be viewed as a colimit involving $n-1$ copies of $\mathbf{2}$ of a diagram that looks like $$\mathbf{2}\leftarrow\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{2}\leftarrow\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{2}\cdots\mathbf{2}\leftarrow\mathbf{1}\to\mathbf{2}$$ where the $\leftarrow$ arrows that map the object of $\mathbf{1}$ to the target object of $\mathbf{2}$ and the $\to$ arrows map it to the source object of $\mathbf{2}$. The $n=0,1$ cases may need to be handled specially, though.

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes, it does. That's why I said "another" way, and also why I left it as a comment, not an answer. To be more specific, the natural numbers themselves are the morphisms $x\to x$, and addition is given by composition (so associativity you get for free, and commutativity is relatively easy to prove). Any monoid may be represented this way, and any category with a single element may be seen as a monoid this way.